# strip some public symbols from a Windows static library

Tags: windows, static-libraries

We want to produce Windows static libraries that have public symbols only for the documented API functions.  We want to strip out all other symbols.

This is easy for a *NIX library; you can use the `strip(1)` utility and specify `--keep-symbol=foo`, and you can even put a whole list of symbols into a file and specify the file.

How can we do this for a Windows library?

A little more detail: suppose we are making a library and it is built from multiple .C files.

`util.c` defines the functions `util_foo()` and `util_bar()`.  `math.c` defines `some_math_func()`.  Then `lib.c` defines the functions `api_func_0()` and `api_func_1()`.  The API functions call the utility and math functions, so those function must not be declared static.  When we compile each .c file, the public symbols are in the object file, and then when we link the object files to make a library, the linker will leave all the public symbols visible.  Once the linker has produced the static library, we only want the symbols `api_func_0` and `api_func_1` visible.

Comment: Never used it, but lib.exe /remove removes stuff.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, I could use `lib.exe /remove` to strip out an object file or maybe even a library function.  I don't see how to use that to leave a function in place, but remove the name of the function from the symbol table.  Oddly, there is `lib.exe /include:symbol` which adds a symbol to the symbol table; but I don't see a corresponding option to strip a symbol from the table.